# Android app(Xamarin Forms) with multidex - start so slow

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-multidex

I created android app wit Xamarin Forms. This is a big application with many nuget packages. Time first star my app was 5 sec. I added multidex in my app. 
Now Time first star my app is 10 sec. Will the user wait for this time? it's funny, no chance.

I tried many options in my project and this is multidex. I have proof of this. This is  "[xamarin evolve app](https://github.com/xamarinhq/app-evolve)". Old version (spring 2016) - don't use multidex, time first load 5 sec. New version app - use multitex, time first load =10 sec.

Any ideas? 10 second for start is very long.  I really need help.

Comment: General advice on startup times: https://blog.xamarin.com/5-ways-boost-xamarin-forms-app-startup-time/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, **your application class (or another important part of your application startup) resides in the secondary DEX file.** You can try moving it to the main DEX file:

**Xamarin.Android** offers a simple way to override the main DEX list:

1. Create a new Text file in your main application root. (Name it `multidex.keep`)
2. Set the **Build Action** to `MultiDexMainDexList`
3. Include any classes you want on the main dex list inside

**Note:** It’s always a good idea to see a previous `multidex.keep` file in your `obj\Debug` folder for a reference.

I hope this helps!

> Reference https://www.jon-douglas.com/2016/09/23/xamarin-android-multidex-keep/